# How to set DNS TTL to 0 using dnsmasq?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I am using dnsmasq as an Internet-facing DNS server.

I want to control TTL, so that no DNS resolver will cache the responses.

How can I set TTL to 0 in dnsmasq.conf?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following page, the option you need might be `--auth-ttl=0`.

Source: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html